# High speed logic level converter circuit

Tags: arduino, digital-logic, level-shifting, 5v, 3.3v

I have been trying to make a 3.3V circuit controlled by an Arduino (5V logic.)

I have used a logic converter circuit similar to the SparkFun/Adafruit ones. My problem is that whenever i try to increase the clock speed of the main circuit up to 1MHz, the circuit does not work.

What options are there for high speed logic conversion? I don't necessarily need bidirectional conversion, however it would be nice if it would be bidirectional.

Comment: Logic level conversion for which bus? And for which speeds? Usally you would use a logic buffer that tolerates 5V input signals when it operates on 3.3V supplies.

Comment: @Justme No particular bus in mind, just parallel connection. As for speed, 1-2mhz woul be enough for me. However up to 8mhz would be great

Comment: Parallel connection between what devices? How many parallel wires? How long would this connection be, and with what kind of wires would this 2 MHz signal pass?

Comment: "similar to ..." isn't a circuit. Can you provide the schematics for what is not working at higher speeds but works at lower?

Comment: "Parallel connection" is a bit vague. Usually we classify UART, SPI, I2C as "Serial Connection". Parallel connection usually refers to 8 or more data lines. Take the character/line printer as a example, usually there is 8+ data lines and a couple of control lines, all of them are unidirectional. If you want bidirectional or even auto-detect directional, then you usually need to go a little bit slower. If you DIY 8-bit 3V to 5V level shifter, using a cheapy 2N2222 x 8 array, you can usually go much higher above 100MHz.

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to use a bidirectional logic shifter when a unidirectional one would do the job. It's a lot easier to make a unidirectional shifter fast.

Comment: Please post a schematic of the circuit that is not working for you, or a link to the Sparkfun circuit, or something ...

Comment: By decreasing your supply voltage your circuit frequency will decrease as well, But in your case, you might wanna change your converter circuit or your Vss

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are bidirectional level shifters designed for I2C, that have internal speed-up logic to improve the risetime. These can certainly do a couple of MHz no problem.

Maxim appnote: https://www.maximintegrated.com/en/design/technical-documents/app-notes/1/1159.html

There is also the pass-transistor type, but you need to add strong-enough pull-ups to get the risetime when translating up. Translating down is no problem.

Example: https://www.ti.com/product/LSF0204D